# Including Descendants("a") or Descendants("b") in XDocument query?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

What is the syntax to grab all Descendants("A") or all Descendants("B")? Sometimes my XML will have "A" or sometimes "B" so I want to grab whichever is available.

I've tried

```
var records = myDocument.Elements().Descendants("A").Descendants("B")
```

But that logically is not correct.

I can do some testing to see if "A" is returned and if not then look for "B" but I was hoping to do it in a single line if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XName a = "A", b = "B";
var records = myDocument.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == a || x.Name == b);
```